# How can I duplicate a symbol?

Tags: ruby, symbols

I want to be able to this with a symbol

```
variable1 = :hello
variable2 = variable1.dup
```

but the `dup` method doesn't work on symbols. Is there an equivalent method for symbols?

Comment: Duplicating a symbol is not a sensible operation, as the whole point of symbols is that there can only be one instance of each. This seems like an X/Y problem; perhaps you could take a step back and tell us what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to create a copy of `variable1` so that I can change it and then compare variable2 to another variable, variable 3. Variable3 might or might not be equal to variable2. I was storing variable3's contents as symbols so performance is better. But after reading your comment and @AndrewMarshalls answer I realize I wasn't thinking of symbols properly.

Comment: Why can't you simply say `variable2 = variable1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, only one instance of a given symbol ever exists. It's just as impossible as trying to do `42.dup`.

You can see that you always get the same object for a symbol with this simple snippet:

```
Array.new(1000) { :foo.object_id }.uniq.size  #=> 1
```

versus a string (which you can `dup`):

```
Array.new(1000) { 'foo'.object_id }.uniq.size  #=> 1000
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I commented above explaining what I was trying to do, but I realized with your answer and Marks comment above I wasn't thinking of symbols properly. Now I'm going to `variable3.to_s` and keep variable1 as a string so I can dup it.

Answer (score 1):

Symbols are not duplicable, there should only be one instance of one symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Two symbols with same content are same entity, you can check it by `.object_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Symbols are immutable. Hence, it does not make sense to duplicate them. Hence, that is designed not to be possible.